# Replace first element in every tuple of a list with a number DrRacket Scheme

Tags: list, tuples, scheme, racket

I want to take a list such as the following:
    '((R.1) (R.5) (R.2) (R.4) (p.3) (t.6) (R.7))

 and replace the letters with numbers as follows:

1. R
2. p
3. t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear if the numbers gets replaced with the letters or vice versa, but it's all the same. You need to make one procedure that does it for one tuple:

```scm
(define (letter->number tuple)
  (cons 
   (case (car tuple)
     ((R) 'first)
     ((p) 'second)
     (else 'third))
   (cdr tuple)))


(letter->number '(R . 1)) ; ==> (first . 1)
(letter->number '(p . 1)) ; ==> (second . 1)
(letter->number '(t . 1)) ; ==> (third . 1)
```

With this you can easily fix a list of these with map:

```scm
(map letter->number '((R . 1) (R . 5) (R . 2) (R . 4) (p . 3) (t . 6) (R . 7)))
; ==> ((first . 1) (first . 5) (first . 2) (first . 4) (second . 3) (third . 6) (first . 7))
```

Note that there were an error in your list. If you do not use spaces on each side of the dotted indicator then Scheme will read the whole thing as a symbol. Thus `'(R . 1)` is a dotted list with `R` and `1`, but `'(R.1)` is a proper list with the symbol `r.1` as the first element and the empty list as the  rest.